# Using variable for json_decode

Tags: php, mysql, json, loops

I need to pass on a variety of variables from mysql queries to create a json file and post every block whenever $sku changes. I can retrieve the data just fine, but when I try to use json_decode, it either says syntax error or returns null, or worse, treats everything as text.

```
$updatedData =  '{
"items" : [
            {
                "barcode" : $barkod,
                "title" : $title,
                "productMainId" : $sku,
                "brandId" : $marka,
                "categoryId" : 387,
                "stockCode" : $sku,
                "dimensionalWeight" : 0,
                "description" : $desc,
                "vatRate" : 0,
                "images" : [
                {
                        "url" : $image0link
                }
            ],
                "attributes" : [
                        {
                        "attributeId" : 343,
                        "attributeValueId" : $gender
                        },
                        {
                        "attributeId" : $mekanizma1,
                        "attributeValueId" : $mekanizma2
                        },
                        {
                        "attributeId" : $kasasekli1,
                        "attributeValueId" : $kasasekli2
                        },
                        {
                        "attributeId" : $camcinsi1,
                        "attributeValueId" : $camcinsi2
                        },
                        {
                        "attributeId" : $camsekli1,
                        "attributeValueId" : $camsekli2
                        },
                        {
                        "attributeId" : $kordonmlz1,
                        "attributeValueId" : $kordonmlz2
                        },
                        {
                        "attributeId" : $kordonrengi1,
                        "attributeValueId" : $kordonrengi2
                        },
                        {
                        "attributeId" : $kasacap1,
                        "attributeValueId" : $kasacap2
                        },
                        {
                        "attributeId" : $kasarengi1,
                        "attributeValueId" : $kasarengi2
                        },
                        {
                        "attributeId" : $sugecirmezlik1,
                        "attributeValueId" : $sugecirmezlik2
                        },
                        {
                        "attributeId" : $kasamlz1,
                        "attributeValueId" : $kasamlz2
                        },
                        {
                        "attributeId" : 47,
                        "customAttributeValue" : $kadranrengi
                        }
                            ],
                "cargoCompanyId" : 1
                "shipmentAddressId" : 409558
                "returningAddressId" : 409558
                }
                ]
    }';
{$json = json_decode($updatedData, true);
if (is_null($json)) {
die("Json decoding failed with error: ". json_last_error());
    }
var_dump($updatedData);}
```

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't try and build the JSON from text, this is probably the main cause of your problem.  Build the appropriate array structure and `json_encode()` the result!

Comment: echo json variable $updatedData, and check weather it is correct or not.
If it's on valid JSON format then definitely `json_decode()`          method work.

Comment: @NigelRen Thank you, that definitely worked. Now I can move on to figuring out how to send the json bit by bit.